# How can I use VSTO project dll for excel in my another .NET application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, office-interop

I have created a project using Visual studio 2010 office template(for excel 2007).and its working fine. I am performing my calculation in ThisWorkbook_Startup() method which is being using in Startup event, defined as

```
    #region VSTO Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisWorkbook_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisWorkbook_Shutdown);

    }

    #endregion
```

and I am using Global.Sheet1,Global.Sheet2 and Global.Sheet3 to write data in excel template and passing to my custom method  as WriteExcel(Globals.Sheet1,Globals.Sheet2,Globals.Sheet3);

I want to use this dll in my another .net project, while I am doing so its initializing  Globals.Sheet1,Globals.Sheet2,Globals.Sheet3 properties with null which is not expected. 
How can I get command on the Global properties to open and write data with defined template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Excel object model methods and properties instead. There is no Global class outside VSTO add-ins (belongs to the VSTO runtime only).

It looks like you need to automate Excel from another application. See [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.

For example, you may find the Worksheets property in the [Workbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835542(v=office.15).aspx) and [Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840672(v=office.15).aspx) classes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eugene Astafiev , actually I am seeking for the way to get  it done as it is, just like it(VSTO) work stand alone.

Comment: VSTO is used for developing Office add-ins only.